# @localizer mvc not finding resources when project name different then namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization

I configured localization in asp.net core which is not working, resources are set to embedded. 
I discover that project name and namespace is different and when set them the same, localizer started translation correctly.

Is there any way to pass different namespace to that localizer then changing the namespace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assembly name can be overridden in csproj by using `<AssemblyName>name</AssemblyName>`